# SQL Server 2012 Trailing spaces ignored in = boolean

Tags: sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012 when searching for a where a column name = `'C CANTU '` it is returning rows where the column in question = `'C CANTU'`.

This is with the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2`.

In SQL Server 2005 these two values are not equal, and these rows are not returned.

Is there a setting in SQL Server 2012 for this? They are `nvarchar` columns. Same scripts ran against each. We are just working on trying to upgrade and found inconsistencies in the final result because of this.

Comment: As an aside, if the column is nvarchar, why are you using `='C...'` and not `=N'C...'`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand this is just a query I used in trying to find the cause of the inconsistency. I did run the query with both N in front of the hard coded string and without it/

Comment: I am not suggesting that adding the N will fix this problem. It is troubling that you found any queries comparing an nvarchar column to a string literal without an N. This can lead to all kinds of problems - false negatives, costly implicit conversions, etc.

Comment: In our scripts we don't have the hard coded string. We are just trying to trim columns that need trimming so update table set col = rtrim(col) where col != rtrim(col). This once again is not our exact code but it gets the point across.

Comment: Could the fact that SQL 2012 ignores the ANSI Padding Enabled setting have anything to do with this?

Comment: Yes, and you need to stop relying on that setting for anything, because it will be ON everywhere regardless of what you do with SET. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx

Comment: This is how SQL works... like forever.

Comment: This is the ANSI standard for comparing strings and is the same way back even in SQL Server 7, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626, also from that article "The SET ANSI_PADDING setting does not affect whether SQL Server pads strings before it compares them. SET ANSI_PADDING only affects whether trailing blanks are trimmed from values being inserted into a table, so it affects storage but not comparisons."

Comment: @leppie and steoleary I don't think "forever" and "back to SQL Server 7" are valid reasons to complain about the question. Today might be their first day with SQL Server, so they don't have the history that you folks do. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I got bitten by it. Best way to learn ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that the column is being adjusted with additional trailing spaces to make the lengths match. A couple of workarounds:

```
DECLARE @p NVARCHAR(255) = N'C CANTU ';

SELECT col FROM dbo.table 
WHERE col LIKE LEFT(@p,1) + '%' AND col + 'x' = @p + 'x'; -- will seek

SELECT col FROM dbo.table 
WHERE col = @p
AND DATALENGTH(col) = DATALENGTH(@p); -- will seek (and add a filter)
```

Note that `LEN()` will ignore trailing spaces, but `DATALENGTH()` will not.

As I mentioned in the comments, I strongly recommend correcting any queries you come across where `nvarchar` columns are compared to string literals without using the `N` prefix.

Comment: I don't think `col + 'x' = N'C CANTU ' + 'x'` is SARGable (without a computed column).

Comment: It's better but `LIKE(@p,1) + '%'` (which I think should be  `LIKE(@p,1) + N'%'` - see bellow comment regarding bad practices) has a low selectivity.

Comment: I don't like this comment :-|

Comment: 1) Existence of an index is a minor problem here. If there is no index then it could be added easily if the user wants/can. But if there is an index then it's for sure that `expression on column = expression` predicate isn't SARGable. 3) Affirmative. 4) Sometimes, simplest solutions are better.

Comment: This is entertaining. Considering if anyone would have read the comment where I was just trying to go update tbl set col = rtrim(col) where col != rtrim(col). This simplest solution would be datalength(col) != datalength(rtrim(col)). Anyhow to address everyone concern about performance on the select statement. If there was an index on col the best thing would be where col = N'C CANTU ' and datalength(col) = datalength(N'C CANTU ')

Comment: Sometimes, it seems that `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (2GB) isn't enough. Some need more (ex. `NVARCHAR(600)`) to express their problems.